# Original machine not available to complete certificate request for Multi-Domain SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, digital-certificate

We use a multi-domain SSL certificate. Each time we add more client URLs, we obtain a new version of the certificate (with the newly added domains) and complete the request on a specific machine that the certificate request was originally created on. The single machine that the CSR was generated was formatted recently. Are there other method(s) that we could complete the certificate requests without that machine being available? Are there better ways of doing this by not being dependent on any single machine?

Please note that by creating a new CSR on another machine, we will need to ask all our clients to validate this new SSL and that is something we would not want to do.

**Update 1**

We got the certificate and the private key from another machine that was using it and imported them to our server. Whenever we try to "Request Certificate with New Key" in certmgr, we get "Enrollment Error - The request contains no certificate template information". How do we resolve this?

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

Comment: You can generate an equivalent CSR on any machine where you have the right private key (which must exist, on the web server that serves the SSL-protected sites, if nowhere else...)

Comment: @IanRoberts That's a lot of relief. Could you point us to a link for instructions?

Comment: If you were just generating CSRs and sending them to a third-party to issue certificates then you're fine, that'll work the same on any machine.  But when you say "we will need to ask all our clients to validate this new SSL", do you mean you had created your own authority certificate on this specific machine and you were issuing your own certificates using that?  If so then unless you've got a backup copy of the authority certificate and its corresponding private key you're stuck, you'll have to create another new authority certificate and get your clients to install that.

Comment: IanRoberts We were just sending it to third-party. The issue here is since its a multidomain ssl and has client URLs embedded, renewing it or creating a new csr might require the clients to re-validate their association with this ssl and that is what we do not want.

Comment: There's nothing special about the certificate being for multiple domains. All that matters to the client browser is whether they trust the _authority_ that issued the certificate. If you generate a new CSR and send it to the same authority to be turned into a certificate then your clients shouldn't notice the difference.